# After Submit -> Scroll Offset if error in a field

Tags: css, parsley.js, powermail

my page does have a fixed header.
Therefore, when there is a wrong entry in a field of the form or a mandatory field not filled, page scrolls to the first field with an error.
Unfortunately, this field is covered by my fixed header and therefore not visible.
Is there a way to change this with some kind of offset to this scroll function?

Please let me know if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple CSS problem. I solve some similar with

```
.tx-powermail:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: first thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem. When submitting the form, it scrolls the first field with an incorrect or missing entry to the top of the page. Therefore it is not seen because it is behind my fixed header.